# Ascii to integer using no library functions

Tags: c, function, pointers

My teacher gave us an assignment where we create a function that reads ASCII digit characters and converts them to a number without using any library functions such as `atoi`. Through some research i came up with this in my own file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sttdef.h>

int main() {

    char testString[] = "123";
    int convertedResult = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; testString[i] != '\0'; i++){
        convertedResult = convertedResult*10 + testString[i] - '0';
        printf("%i\n",convertedResult);
        if (testString[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While this works on its own i have to use the main file he gave us to call on this specific function.

```
 char *asciiToInteger(char *inputString, int *integerPtr) {
     return inputString;
 }
```

I'm a bit confused as to how to proceed from here? attatched picture is main

[image]

Comment: This function has to be in a file other than main file?? or u just need to add a funtion?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the signature of your teacher's function. What are the expected inputs and outputs? I mean, it seems rather clear that they expect you to put the input in `inputString` and the output in `integerPtr`, but why should the function return a `char *` instead of just returning an `int` and ditching `integerPtr`?

Comment: the function does need to be in another file other than main.
im at a loss also with the pointer expected outputs. 
unfortunately i cant use strtol()) as that is a function and i can only use the function prototype defined by my professor

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I would expect it to return a pointer to the first non-converted character, that is quite common in various ways (basically this is a mixup of `strtol()`) and useful.

Comment: Please, don't post code as images. Code is text, please post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stddef.h>  

    char * asciiToInteger(char *inputString, int *integerPtr){
           int convertedResult =0;

           for(int i = 0; inputString[i] != '\0'; i++){
            convertedResult = convertedResult*10 + inputString[i] - '0';

          }
          *integerPtr=convertedResult;


         return inputString;
         }

 int main() {  
    char testString[] = "123";
    int  integerPtr;
    asciiToInteger(testString, &integerPtr) ;
    printf("%d\n",integerPtr);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a couple of problems:

- It assumes the entire string is digits
- It checks for the end of string twice

I think a better implementation would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *asciiToInteger(const char *inputString, int *value)
{
  int result = 0;
  while (isdigit((unsigned int) *inputString))
  {
    result *= 10;
    result += *inputString++ - '0';
  }
  *value = result;
  return inputString;
}
```

This returns a pointer to the first non-converted character, which might be to the end of string marker if the string is all digits. I added `const` on the strings of course, since this converter is just reading from the strings.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an assignment like this the first step is to make sure you understand what the function is supposed to do. Your question has no such description so that is the place to start.

From the behavior of the `main` function it seems to be something like:

1. If the first character in the input string is **not** a digit return NULL
2. If the first character in the input string **is** a digit convert all leading digits to an integer stored in the object pointed to by `integerPtr` and return a pointer to the character following the converted digits.

Examples:

```
inputString = "a123b67" --> return NULL

inputString = "123b67"  --> *integerPtr = 123 and return a pointer to the 'b' in the input
```

That could look something like this:

```
char *asciiToInteger(char *inputString, int *integerPtr) {
    if (*inputString < '0' || *inputString > '9') 
        return NULL;  // no leading digit

    *integerPtr = 0;
    do
    {
        *integerPtr = *integerPtr * 10 + *inputString - '0';
        ++inputString;
    } while (*inputString >= '0' && *inputString <= '9');
    return inputString;
}
```

Notice that the code above can't handle negative integers.